# Creating a global Julia environment

Tags: julia, package-managers

In Julia I can use the global environment or environments attached to a certain path.

Is there a way to create new global environments?
Something I can activate using `] activate myenv` instead of changing the path etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the [`PKG.jl` documentation](https://pkgdocs.julialang.org/).
Specifically at [Working with Environment](https://pkgdocs.julialang.org/v1/environments/).

You will see an option for [Shared Environments](https://pkgdocs.julialang.org/v1/environments/#Shared-environments).
So what you need to do is:

```
] activate --shared myenv
```

If it exist it will be activated, if it is not, it will be created.

Those environments are global just like the default `@1.x` environment.